# VS 2013 TFS : Multiple users working on same file

Tags: tfs

We are using VS 2013 TFS. We have multiple programmer working on one file at a same time. Is there any better approach we can use where we don’t lose others work and we all can work in harmony? We tried branching but unfortunately, it doesn’t support intelisense.

Comment: Get the latest changes before checking in and stop overwriting each other's changes when resolving conflicts?

Comment: And what do you mean "doesn't support intelisense"? Branching has nothing to do with intellisense.

Comment: considering the merge function on the TFS, i think getting the latest changes before checking in it's the way to go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enable the **Multiple check-out** feature by going to Settings, Source Control, Check-out settings and click on Enable multiple check-out check box. This will allow multiple programmers to check-out the same file in the same time.

Comment: You don't need to checkout a file to edit it, in TFS. Besides, if they only permit one check-out, the file will be locked for anyone else, so the OPs problem wouldn't arise in the first place.